# addEventListener and jQuery click incompatible in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I'm noticing an event listener issue with jQuery 2.1.4 and PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X). When I trigger a click event through jQuery, the `document.addEventListener` never catches it, while `on('click'` does.

```
var doc = $(document);

doc.on('click', function() {
    console.log('on click'); // fires
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log('listener click'); // never fires
});

doc.click();
```

When I trigger a click manually, both work:

```
var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window);
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Am I missing something, or is this just a PhantomJS issue?

Comment: It works as expected in Chrome. I haven't tried firefox but I've never had any problems before.

Comment: this issue sounds really familiar, but i haven't really worked with jQuery in a few years now so i can't remember what it was.... it's likely caused by the fact that jQuery has it's own event system, and the jQuery triggered event isn't leaving that system for some reason in this case.

Comment: What does `jQuery.isWindow(document)` give you? Work through this area to see where it's stopping: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L378

Comment: That method returns `false`. Debugging the jQuery event code, `onlyHandlers` is `true`, which fails the condition on line 379.

Comment: that's weird.... that shouldn't be true. it only gets set to true if you use `.triggerHandler()`

Comment: I have a `addEventListener` attached to a form, it works on Chrome but not with PhantomJS. Any idea to solve it?

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  Test passes in Chrome (adds event listener), but fails in PhantomJS...